# Invalid code signing entitlements error upon iTunes Connect validation for iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing, bundle-identifier

I am attempting to validate my iOS app in Xcode. However, upon validation, I receive the following error:

[image: iTunes Connect Validation]

> **The following issues were found during validation:**
>
> - Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'VQ27FEWWTE.Veniteck.Solutions.Radio-Malayalam' for key 'application-idenfier' in 'Payload/Radio Malayalam.app/Radio Malayalam' is not supported. This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by the bundle identifier.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have tried everything and nothing is helping, believe me, sometimes just closing the XCode, shutting down the system helps. When you again start the system, the same thing whil work like a charm. I have been a victim of Apple's Troll.

Comment: This is it. Instead of jumping into it, we need to go take a nap. And then when we come back, it helps.

Comment: LOL. WOW. It worked. (restarted XCode but didn't restart OS X) "Hello, tech support. Have you tried restarting XCode and your MacBook?"

Comment: This did it for me too. Thank you :). You probably need to do a full 'QUIT' on Xcode, not just close the window.

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure your version number is the same as what is in itunes connect.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps to fix the problem:

**1)** Close XCode, and restart your computer. Sometimes errors like this happen because you're in need of a restart

**2)** Try changing your bundle ID to have no `-`'s or `_`'s in it. Try to only use numbers, letters, and the dots needed in your ID. something like `com.myDomain.myApp`, avoid `com.myDomain.this-is_my+App`

**3)** Make sure that your bundle id follows this syntax: `TLD.domain.appName`, so you should have your bundle ID set to `com.venitecksolutions.Radio-Malayalam`. Your team ID is not needed. Here is an example when creating a new project:

[image]

**4)** Try changing the bundle ID, create an entirely new app with a compleatly different, unique ID, like `com.venitecksolutions.RadioMalayalam`. Creating an entirely new project, and an entirely new application in `iTunesConnect`

**5)** If all else fails, try entirely re-creating the project, and copying over all of the code to the new project. Sometimes the project is corrupted and you just need to move all of your code, and nib or storyboards over to a completely new file.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the error message, there is a specific syntax which you must follow for your application-identifier key.

> This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by the bundle identifier.

Make sure you follow this syntax, otherwise the app will not validate. Use…

```
VQ27FEWWTE.com.venitecksolutions.Radio-Malayalam
```

Comment: You mean I will have to create a new ap id.?

Answer (score 0):

I did everything. Nothing worked. The problem was my mobile provision in dev portal was invalid. So, i edit and updated it and then quit, restart Xcode. Now everything is fine.