# Can't Distribute because of Code Signing Entitlements Error

Tags: xcode, error-handling, code-signing

I've finished my project, but I can't submit the huge Update, because Apple made the distribution dead again...

Here is the following error I am receiving:

[image: http://s2.postimg.org/pf5ghkjd5/Screen_Shot_2014_10_18_at_21_11_46.png]

My entitlements plist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
    <array/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution (a bit unconventional though): http://stackoverflow.com/a/21746866/1336105

Comment: Tried it, hasn't solved the problem :(.

Comment: Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20622401/1336105

Comment: What is in your entitlements.plist file?  Have you tried removing the offending key and then enabling in-app purchase via capabilities in XCode (assuming your app uses in-app purchase)?

Comment: Asif Asif: Yes, I've tried this 5 steps.

Comment: Paulw11: I've in-app purchases, now I've tried to remove the .entitlements file and replace it, result will write result in 5 minds.

Comment: Same error :(. I've the following inside my entitlements plist:

Comment: That file doesn't contain the key mentioned, so is it possible that you have another entitlements file in your project somewhere

Comment: Pualw11: I searched for it, but I haven't got :/.